# Each UNION SELECT working fine, but throwing an error upon UNION

Tags: sql, mariadb, union

Hoping someone can help a beginner in MariaDB 10.3 with a UNION of 2 queries.

Each of the below queries work fine on themselves, but when I want to combine the outcomes in a UNION, it throws 'Division by 0' warnings.

**SQL 1:**

```
    WITH hv_sub AS (SELECT hv.portfolio,
                                    hv.price_date,
                                    SUM(hv.VALUE) AS curValue,
                                    SUM(hv.VALUE) + IFNULL(SUM(tv.cashflow),0) AS netValue,
                                    SUM(hv.retrn) AS portfolio_retrn
                            FROM holdings_VIEW_day_by_day hv
                                LEFT JOIN transactions_VIEW tv ON tv.tr_date = hv.price_date AND hv.portfolio = tv.portfolio AND hv.isin = tv.isin
                            WHERE hv.isin <> 'EU0000000000'
                            GROUP BY hv.portfolio, hv.price_date
                            ORDER BY hv.price_date),

            portfolio_retrn_pct AS (SELECT hv_sub.portfolio,
                                                        hv_sub.price_date,
                                                        hv_sub.portfolio_retrn,
                                                        hv_sub.netValue / LAG(hv_sub.curValue,1) OVER (PARTITION BY hv_sub.portfolio ORDER BY hv_sub.price_date) AS portfolio_retrn_pct
                                                FROM hv_sub)

    SELECT prp.portfolio,
                'Portfolio',
                CAST(YEAR(prp.price_date) AS CHAR) AS yr,
                CONCAT(ROUND(100*(EXP(SUM(LN(prp.portfolio_retrn_pct)))-1),1),"%") AS portfolio_twRoR,
                SUM(prp.portfolio_retrn) AS portfolio_retrn,
                0 AS yrEndValue
        FROM portfolio_retrn_pct prp
        GROUP BY prp.portfolio, YEAR(prp.price_date)
```

**SQL 2:**

```
WITH maxDates AS (SELECT hv.portfolio,
                                    hv.isin,
                                    YEAR(hv.price_date) as yr,
                                    MAX(hv.price_date) as maxDate
                            FROM holdings_VIEW_day_by_day hv
                            GROUP BY YEAR(hv.price_date), hv.portfolio, hv.isin),
        yrEndValues AS (SELECT md.*, hv.value
                                FROM holdings_VIEW_day_by_day hv
                                JOIN maxDates md ON md.portfolio = hv.portfolio AND md.isin = hv.isin AND md.maxDate = hv.price_date
                                GROUP BY hv.portfolio, hv.isin, YEAR(hv.price_date)
                                ORDER BY YEAR(hv.price_date), hv.stock_name)

SELECT hv.portfolio,
            hv.stock_name,
            CAST(YEAR(hv.price_date) AS CHAR) as yr,
            CONCAT(ROUND(100*(EXP(SUM(LN(hv.retrn_pct)))-1),1),"%") AS twRoR,
            ROUND(SUM(hv.retrn),0) AS retrn,
            ROUND(yEV.value,0) AS yrEndValue
    FROM holdings_VIEW_day_by_day hv
    LEFT JOIN yrEndValues yEV ON hv.portfolio = yEV.portfolio AND hv.isin = yEV.isin AND YEAR(hv.price_date) = yEV.yr
    GROUP BY hv.portfolio, hv.stock_name, YEAR(hv.price_date)
    ORDER BY YEAR(hv.price_date), hv.portfolio, hv.stock_name, EXP(SUM(LN(hv.retrn_pct))) DESC
```

**UNION SQL:**

```
WITH maxDates AS (SELECT hv1.portfolio,
                                    hv1.isin,
                                    YEAR(hv1.price_date) as yr,
                                    MAX(hv1.price_date) as maxDate
                            FROM holdings_VIEW_day_by_day hv1
                            GROUP BY YEAR(hv1.price_date), hv1.portfolio, hv1.isin),

        yrEndValues AS (SELECT md.*, hv.value
                                FROM holdings_VIEW_day_by_day hv
                                JOIN maxDates md ON md.portfolio = hv.portfolio AND md.isin = hv.isin AND md.maxDate = hv.price_date
                                GROUP BY hv.portfolio, hv.isin, YEAR(hv.price_date)
                                ORDER BY YEAR(hv.price_date), hv.stock_name),

        hv_sub AS (SELECT hv2.portfolio,
                                hv2.price_date,
                                SUM(hv2.VALUE) AS curValue,
                                SUM(hv2.VALUE) + IFNULL(SUM(tv.cashflow),0) AS netValue,
                                SUM(hv2.retrn) AS portfolio_retrn
                        FROM holdings_VIEW_day_by_day hv2
                            LEFT JOIN transactions_VIEW tv ON tv.tr_date = hv2.price_date AND hv2.portfolio = tv.portfolio AND hv2.isin = tv.isin
                        WHERE hv2.isin <> 'EU0000000000'
                        GROUP BY hv2.portfolio, hv2.price_date
                        ORDER BY hv2.price_date),

        portfolio_retrn_pct AS (SELECT hv_sub.portfolio,
                                                    hv_sub.price_date,
                                                    hv_sub.portfolio_retrn,
                                                    hv_sub.netValue / LAG(hv_sub.curValue,1) OVER (PARTITION BY hv_sub.portfolio ORDER BY hv_sub.price_date) AS portfolio_retrn_pct
                                            FROM hv_sub)


(SELECT hv.portfolio,
            hv.stock_name,
            CAST(YEAR(hv.price_date) AS CHAR) as yr,
            CONCAT(ROUND(100*(EXP(SUM(LN(hv.retrn_pct)))-1),1),"%") AS twRoR,
            ROUND(SUM(hv.retrn),0) AS retrn,
            ROUND(yEV.value,0) AS yrEndValue
    FROM holdings_VIEW_day_by_day hv
        LEFT JOIN yrEndValues yEV ON hv.portfolio = yEV.portfolio AND hv.isin = yEV.isin AND YEAR(hv.price_date) = yEV.yr
    GROUP BY hv.portfolio, hv.stock_name, YEAR(hv.price_date)
    ORDER BY YEAR(hv.price_date), hv.portfolio, hv.stock_name, EXP(SUM(LN(hv.retrn_pct))) DESC)

UNION

(SELECT prp.portfolio,
            '_Portfolio',
            CAST(YEAR(prp.price_date) AS CHAR) AS yr,
            CONCAT(ROUND(100*(EXP(SUM(LN(prp.portfolio_retrn_pct)))-1),1),"%") AS portfolio_twRoR,
            SUM(prp.portfolio_retrn) AS portfolio_retrn,
            0
    FROM portfolio_retrn_pct prp
    GROUP BY prp.portfolio, YEAR(prp.price_date))

ORDER BY yr, stock_name;
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

**FURTHER FINDING:**
*The warnings disappear as soon as I remove the global UNION SORT BY at the end.*

(I'm also happy to take any ways to optimize these queries... it doesn't look elegant and takes quite some time (15secs) to produce its output)

Thank you

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you start!

Comment: I remember getting non-sequitur errors when I had a (n)varchar column in the first set that SQL decided was only n chars wide, but the same column in the second set was wider. Don't remember the error...it was a long time ago...but I remember it being nonsensical. For giggles...try explicitly casting both columns to a large, known width...in the second column (hv.stock_name) vs '_Portfolio'

Comment: Also...can't see that there's a point in having an order by in the set before the union...or any of the with clauses for that matter.

Comment: Tried casting both the first 2 columns, but no success unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion.
I'm aware of the ORDERING, just haven't bothered taking them out until I get it to work

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that your individual queries are not processing the entire result set.  So they are returning rows *before* they get to the problematic row.

In any case, division by zero is easily avoidable using `nullif()`.  So wherever you have division, use it.  For instance:

```
(hv_sub.netValue / 
 NULLIF(LAG(hv_sub.curValue, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY hv_sub.portfolio ORDER BY hv_sub.price_date), 0)
) AS portfolio_retrn_pct
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I tried to insert a NULLIF, but it didn't actually avoid the error, so took it out again.